# I am trying to load data from redux store on click and updating the state, but the data from state is not getting updated on the click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

//Below is the state

```
const [ showDiary, setShowDiary ] = useState({});
const { showContent, showDate, showImages } = showDiary;
```

// Code to get the data from redux and update the state

```
 const getDiary = (e, id) => {
     const diary = diaries.diaries.find(diary => {
  return diary._id === id
});
console.log(diary);
setShowDiary({  ...showDiary, showContent: diary.content, showDate: diary.date, showImages: diary.images })
  };
```

//Now in console i am getting correct data for all clicks, but the state is not getting updated and also the data on click is not getting updated.
// Note: diaries.diaries is the data that is stored in redux store
EDIT
//Bringing in Redux Store

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  diaries: state.diary
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, {
    deleteDiary
  }
) (DiaryItem)
```

//Html where i show the content

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#fullcontent' onClick={e => getDiary(e, _id)}>View Full</button>
<button className="btn btn-outline-default">Edit</button>
<button className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={e => deletes(e, _id)}>Delete</button>

<div className="modal fade" id="fullcontent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body" style={{height: height / 2, overflow: 'scroll'}}>
                  {showContent}
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//Props from where i am getting the state

```
const DiaryItem = ({diary: {date, content, images, _id}, deleteDiary, diaries}) => {
```

Comment: Can you post the code around where and how the component is connected to the redux store

Comment: @Sushanth-- updated the code

Comment: Also what triggers `getDiary`. It is very hard to say without looking at the entire component as it would rely on assumptions

Comment: @Sushanth-- updated the code as per your request....I have bunch of view full buttons and on the click of that button I want specific data filtered from redux state....and the data is also getting filtered and displayed in console....but it doesnt update on the screen

Comment: `Diaries` is passed as `props` to the component and it is owned by the redux store. Props are only read only. So when you want to update `Dairies`, you need to update that in the redux store. That is one issue. `showContent` is different as you have extracted into the local state. try putting in the `console.log` statement in render and see if it logs anything once you click the button

Comment: Any way you can do a spin up a fiddle with working example?  Unclear why you are setting your data to the local state when you have them readily via `props` courtesy of redux.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I am not trying to update the state, on click function i am passing the id, and throught that id i am filtering the data from redux store, thats it.Here the redux store is not getting updated at all. And i have already console logged the filtered data and i am getting the data in console as expected , but when i update the local state with that data, it is not being updated or the new data is not being shown. It always render the previous data

Comment: @Kyle In redux i have an array of data , and in components on click function i only want a single object from that array, so i am filtering the data on click and setting that single object to the local state.

Comment: Were you able to put console log statements and see if the render is called when you click an item. Also can you post your entire component instead of chunks ?

Comment: @Sushanth-- No, i was talking about consoles in getDiary function

Comment: I get that they are logging correctly. I was referring to the one in render ( which needs to be added ), if it gets called or not

Answer (score 0):

Is `diaries` a `Promise`? Does it need to be `async`? I feel like that's where your problem is. If it is a Promise, I'm not sure you're resolving it correctly. But I suspect that it may *not* be a Promise, in which case you wouldn't need `async`?

Side note:
If you're using `filter`, but you only want the first element, you can just use `find`:

```
const diary = diaries.diaries.find(diary => {
  return diary._id === id
});
```

Then you don't have to keep saying `diary[0]`.

Comment: its a prop via connect HOC from react-redux, but after filtering the data , i am updating the state , but the data is not being updated, so i think my state is not being updated after the data is filtered, not sure why

Comment: I'll update my answer to ask more questions. I know it isn't an answer yet, just need more clarification.

Comment: Still not getting the results after removing async/await, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `hooks` anyway, try the below.  `reduxjs` recommends that you use `memoize` on your selectors.  https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/master/README.md#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { memoize } from "lodash.memoize";

// first, create a selector
const getDiaryById = id => createSelector(
    state => state.diary.diaries,
    diaries => memoize(
        diaryId => diaries.find(item => item.id === diaryId)
    )
);

function App() {
    const [diaryId, setDiaryId] = useState(null);
    const [myDiary, setMyDiary] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const diary = useSelector(getDiaryById(diaryId));

        // this set function really depends on your use case
        setMyDiary(diary);

    }, [diaryId]); // only run if the diaryId changes

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="diarySelector">Select A Diary</label>
            <select name="diarySelector" id="diarySelector" onChange={e=> setDiaryId(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="1">3</option>
                <option value="1">4</option>
            </select>

            <pre>{JSON.stringify(myDiary, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```